# Adding legend to d3.js force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add a legend to d3.js force directed graph. I have the graph without the legend working perfectly fine. I am following the instructions at https://gist.github.com/ZJONSSON/3918369 Here is the parts where I modified the code:

```
  const node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .join("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .attr("fill", color )
      .attr("data-legend",function(d) { return d.lineage}) // XXX: added for legend
      .call(drag(simulation));

  node.append("title")
      .text(d => d.id);

// added this block    
  legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","legend")
    .attr("transform","translate(50,30)")
    .style("font-size","12px")
    .call(d3.legend)

// end add block
```

Once I add the part between `// added this block` I get the error `chart = TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. I am coloring the nodes by the property lineage of each node.

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you try it with a "var" or "const" declaration in front of the word legend?

Comment: both `var` or `const` give the same error.